# OpenAPI (formerly Swagger) spec and inbound/outbound REST calls

Tags: rest-api, integration

I have read many articles as how to expose the Apex class as a REST API or call the external REST API from Apex. How does OpenAPI (fka Swagger) work with Salesforce in inbound or outbound Rest API calls.

Answer (score 1):

A service that lives outside of Salesforce and documents its APIs via OpenAPI (formerly Swagger) specification can be consumed by Salesforce in a somewhat automated fashion. The creation of the client calling this service from the Salesforce platform and the callout itself must be done in a very specific way, via a framework that Salesforce refers to as `External Services`. Apex REST is for inbound (to Salesforce) calls. OpenAPI is not available in an automated fashion via Salesforce platform as a documentation format for Apex REST services (upvote this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cQsxQAE))

See External Services docs and/or [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/external-services) for more info.